# Deleting undesired characters at the end of a char

Tags: c++

With this code below I dont know how to delete the undesired characters appearing at the end of the message array. It is compulsory for me to use char, can't use strings, because of the rest of my code.
recvbuf is also a char* recvbuf=new char

```
                char* message=new char[140];
                for (int i=1; i<141; i++){
                    message[i-1]=recvbuf[i];
                }
                printf("Message: %s\n", message);
                delete[]recvbuf;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Though it is recommended you use strings to implement this code, the problem can be fixed by manually appending a null character `\0` at the end of your char array.
You can introduce it as:

```
    char* message=new char[141];
    for (int i=1; i<141; i++){
        message[i-1]=recvbuf[i];
    }
    message[140] = '\0'; //newly introduced line.
    printf("Message: %s\n", message);
    delete[]recvbuf;
```

**NOTE 1:** The size of the array was increased from 140 to 141 during initialization to make room for the `\0` character at the end.

Cheers!